# Wrong output in searching a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I created a linked list and then used the following search function to get the position of the data field,but it returns the value as the last element of the linked list.I am unable to guess why

```
int search(struct node *curr,int d,int i)
{
if (!(curr-1))
    return(0);
if (curr->data == d)
    return i;

else
{
    i++;
    search(curr->link,d,i);
}
 }
```

I used the following statement to control it from main:

m=search(first,data,i) //here first is the pointer to first element to first element and data is element to search

Comment: *search()* should better return a `struct node *`, no? Also the `if (!(curr-1))` is strange... `curr` being a pointer. Does the func returns an index? `0` wouldn't be a valid index?

Comment: try if(!curr) instead of (curr-1)

Comment: since you are using linked list.... the nodes need not be contiguous in memory hence `!(curr-1)` isn't correct....

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!(curr-1))
```

Why `-1`?

```
else
{
    i++;
    search(curr->link,d,i);
}
```

You have forgotten the `return` statement. Otherwise, the return value is undefined. Then, your recursive `search` function might look like:

```
int search(struct node *curr, int d, int i)
{
    if (curr == NULL)
        return 0; /* If 1 <= i <= n */
    else if (curr->data == d)
        return i;
    else
        return search(curr->link, d, i + 1); 
}
```

Comment: ,thanks,it sort of worked,but now getting an output:56 not found if d=56.

Comment: @user1369975: We don't have enough code to say what doesn't work.

Comment: Another point @Kirilenko why is last return needed I mean previous both returns should suffice

Answer (score 1):

Why *recursion*? You learn bad habits.

```
int search(struct node* curr, int d, int i)
{
    if (NULL == curr)
    {
       return 0;
    }
    i = 1;
    while(curr->data != d)
    {
        if (NULL != curr->link)
        {
            curr = curr->link;
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Although recursion is more natural and really important in many scenarios with data structures, this is certainly NOT one of them. Hence iteration gets +1

Comment: Thanks. Usage of recursion in the language like C requires deep understanding of consequences. In fact recursion example above may be _tail recursion_ and compiler may optimize it in way that stack wouldn't grow.

Comment: Agreed. But as far as i know, wherever data structures are taught in c (i learned the same way), recursion, call stack and memory considerations were taught along / before. One can't actually program in c for any reasonable software without knowing these at all. I hope OP was aware of most.

Comment: Who told that you have to learn C in class? Or you have a teacher? I started learning programming in Pascal not knowing what is stack and heap. I learnt what the stack is first time I tried to code assembler. Not knowing what the heap is in DOS days kicked my a* when my program was unable to launch external tool. So I learnt by experience and when I studied programming I know all of this already.

Comment: hehe... yeah but following the academic stream is more common. Self taughts are always fewer relatively speaking.

Comment: @Michael any reason why return is needed at last place

Comment: @user1369975 Is this a question?